# Calculate time difference in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, time

In my data, the form looks like below:

**Sunday|10:00-22:00**

**Saturday|10:00-22:00**

**Monday|10:00-19:00**

**Tuesday|10:00-18:00**

**Friday|10:00-19:00**

I do not know how to compute the time diff.

I need to know each person's time duration. Thanks!

Or just give me a hint, that is totally fine.

Comment: Do you have data stored in a column like this: `10:00-22:00`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to use a couple of functions `instr`, `substr` and `julianday` to get what you need.

**Table**

Let's say your table looked like this:

```
create table test (day, timespan);
insert into test values ('Sunday', '10:00-22:00');
insert into test values ('Saturday', '10:00-22:00');
insert into test values ('Monday' , '10:00-19:00');
insert into test values ('Tuesday', '10:00-18:00');
insert into test values ('Friday', '10:00-19:00');
```

**Query**

Run the following query to give you time in hours

```
select
  day,
  timespan,
  round( 24 * (
    julianday('2000-01-01 ' || substr(timespan, instr(timespan, '-')+1, 10) || ':00') - 
    julianday('2000-01-01 ' || substr(timespan, 1, instr(timespan, '-')-1) || ':00')
  ), 1) as hrs
from test;
```

**Results**

```
day         timespan     hours        
----------  -----------  ----------
Sunday      10:00-22:00  12.0      
Saturday    10:00-22:00  12.0      
Monday      10:00-19:00  9.0       
Tuesday     10:00-18:00  8.0
Friday      10:00-19:00  9.0
```

**Explanation**

If your time is stored in a column like this: `10:00-22:00`, then we should split the start and end times. To do that, we find the location of the `-` using `instr`. For example, `instr('10:00-22:00', '-')` will give you 6. That means `-` is in 6th position.

Knowing where the dash is, we can find the start time by taking characters from start till the dash. We can get end date by getting characters starting after the dash to the end of the string. I just chose to get 10 characters after the dash using `substr`.

Because we just have a time and note a date, I created a fictitious date of 2000-01-01 and prepended the start time to it to create the start date/time. I did the same thing with the end date.

`julianday` of start and end date gives us the number of days that have passed since a certain day, which happens to be US declaration of independence day. So, subtracting julianday of end date from the julianday of start date will give you the number of days. Multiply that by 24 to get hours.